# Matrix derivative of $\frac{d(xA)}{dx}$

Tags: analysis, matrix-calculus

My problem was to find the matrix derivative of:

$$
 F =\begin{bmatrix}0&0&x_1\\0&0&x_2\end{bmatrix} 
$$

with respect to  $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$. My first thought is to decompose F into:

$$
F =  \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\end{bmatrix} 
$$

but then it is still unclear how to proceed, since I only have derivative of $Ax$, but not $xA$ with respect to $x$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need a rank-$3$ tensor viz. $\frac{d(x_iA_j)}{dx_k}=\delta_{ik}A_j$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $F(x) =\begin{bmatrix}0&0&x_1\\0&0&x_2\end{bmatrix}$.
Note that $F(x+h) -F(x) = F(h)$. Hence $F$ is its own derivative, that is,
$DF(x)h = F(h)$.